# How to bring overlay view to front in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a dropdown like this [Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zipxk.png) , Most of the tutorial suggested to use overlay for the same, but when implemented I get the UI [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNbeg.png)
Its coming behind the next view which in turn doesn't give the look I wanted, How to bring the overlay view to front, It seems to be easy in UIKit and but doesn't seem to work with Swift UI, Any suggestion?

with .zIndex(1) brings it up but when its embedded to list it doesn't work,Any suggestions ?
sample code

```
import SwiftUI

struct DropdownOption: Hashable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    
    public static func == (lhs: DropdownOption, rhs: DropdownOption) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}

struct DropdownRow: View {
    var option: DropdownOption
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if let onOptionSelected = self.onOptionSelected {
                onOptionSelected(self.option)
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.option.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}

struct Dropdown: View {
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                    DropdownRow(option: option, onOptionSelected: self.onOptionSelected)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: CGFloat(options.count) * 30, maxHeight: 250)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector: View {
    @State private var shouldShowDropdown = false
    @State private var selectedOption: DropdownOption? = nil
    var placeholder: String
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    private let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.shouldShowDropdown.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(selectedOption == nil ? placeholder : selectedOption!.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedOption == nil ? Color.gray: Color.black)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: self.shouldShowDropdown ? "arrowtriangle.up.fill" : "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 9, height: 5)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 9, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: self.buttonHeight)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Image("top-image")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .scaledToFit()
                if self.shouldShowDropdown {
                    Spacer(minLength: buttonHeight + 10)
                    Dropdown(options: self.options, onOptionSelected: { option in
                        shouldShowDropdown = false
                        selectedOption = option
                        self.onOptionSelected?(option)
                    })
                }
            }, alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.white)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var address: String = ""
    
    static var uniqueKey: String {
        UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    static let options: [DropdownOption] = [
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Sunday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Monday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Tuesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Wednesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Thursday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Friday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Saturday")
    ]
    
        static var previews: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<4) { index in
                HStack(){
                    DropdownSelector(
                        placeholder: "Day of the week",
                        options: options,
                        onOptionSelected: { option in
                            print(option)
                        })
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .zIndex(1)
                    
                    DropdownSelector(
                        placeholder: "Day of the week",
                        options: options,
                        onOptionSelected: { option in
                            print(option)
                        })
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        
               }.zIndex(1)
                
           }

        }
        Group {
            TextField("Full Address", text: $address)
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 45)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like https://getdigitaltech.com/ios-the-right-way-to-create-dropdown-in-swift-ui/#respond also specifies the same ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to apply your `.zIndex(1)` modifier on `HStack` containing your `DropdownSelector` like this

```
HStack(){
    DropdownSelector(
        placeholder: "Day of the week",
        options: options,
        onOptionSelected: { option in
            print(option)
        })
    .padding(.horizontal)
    
    DropdownSelector(
        placeholder: "Day of the week",
        options: options,
        onOptionSelected: { option in
            print(option)
        })
    .padding(.horizontal)
}
.zIndex(1)
```

Comment: perfect, you saved my lot of time.

Comment: It works perfect but doesn't work with list embedded.

Comment: any idea on this

Comment: name: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5096960/khawar-ali any idea

Comment: The views you want to bring to the front/back need to be on the same levels. e.g two views in the same VStack.

Comment: does that mean when embed in list view the dropdown doesn't work as expected, I have modified and added a new UI, any workaround do you suggest ?

Comment: You need to apply `.zIndex(1)` on the List.
Because List is one that is on the same level as other views.

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Comment: I modified the code, in the question , but it doesn't seem to be working to me

Comment: `.zIndex(indexToBringForward == index ? 1 : 0 )` with  state variable `@state var indexToBringForward` to control the UI position. I am posting complete code on you other question.