# How to bring the overlay of one section in front always in swift UI inside list view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I was trying to create the UI similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1xkc.png), went through the few articles and found that overlay should be used to create the same UI, However everything is fine unless List or any iterating view is used, when the overlay crosses the other sections frame it doesn't seem to be behaving as expected?

```
        List  { // 3 elements 
            
            HStack(){
                DropdownSelector(
                    placeholder: "Day of the week",
                    options: options,
                    onOptionSelected: { option in
                        print(option)
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .zIndex(1)
                
                DropdownSelector(
                    placeholder: "Day of the week",
                    options: options,
                    onOptionSelected: { option in
                        print(option)
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .zIndex(1)
            }.zIndex(1)
        }
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think this is the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314668/how-to-bring-overlay-view-to-front-in-swiftui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bring overlay view to front in swiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314668/how-to-bring-overlay-view-to-front-in-swiftui)

Comment: The question was asked by me only, it doesn't tell about the list view embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `.zIndex(1)` value with a state variable like in the code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct DropdownOption: Hashable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    
    public static func == (lhs: DropdownOption, rhs: DropdownOption) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}

struct DropdownRow: View {
    var option: DropdownOption
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if let onOptionSelected = self.onOptionSelected {
                onOptionSelected(self.option)
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.option.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}

struct Dropdown: View {
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                    DropdownRow(option: option, onOptionSelected: self.onOptionSelected)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: CGFloat(options.count) * 30, maxHeight: 250)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector: View {
    @State private var shouldShowDropdown = false
    @State private var selectedOption: DropdownOption? = nil
    var placeholder: String
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
    var onDropdownSelected: (() -> Void)
    private let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.shouldShowDropdown.toggle()
            onDropdownSelected()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(selectedOption == nil ? placeholder : selectedOption!.value)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedOption == nil ? Color.gray: Color.black)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: self.shouldShowDropdown ? "arrowtriangle.up.fill" : "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 9, height: 5)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 9, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: self.buttonHeight)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Image("top-image")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .scaledToFit()
                if self.shouldShowDropdown {
                    Spacer(minLength: buttonHeight + 10)
                    Dropdown(options: self.options, onOptionSelected: { option in
                        shouldShowDropdown = false
                        selectedOption = option
                        self.onOptionSelected?(option)
                    })
                }
            }, alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.white)
        )
    }
}

struct CellStatus  {
    var zIndex: Double
    var isOpen: Bool
}

struct DropdownSelectorView: View {

    @State private var address: String = ""
    @State private var indexToBringForward = 0
    @State private var eachCellStatus: [CellStatus] = Array(repeating: CellStatus(zIndex: 0, isOpen: false), count: 6)
    
    static var uniqueKey: String {
        UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    let options: [DropdownOption] = [
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Sunday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Monday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Tuesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Wednesday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Thursday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Friday"),
        DropdownOption(key: uniqueKey, value: "Saturday")
    ]
    
    private var gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200))]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach((0..<6), id: \.self) { index in
                    DropdownSelector(
                        placeholder: "Day of the week",
                        options: options,
                        onOptionSelected: { option in
                            print(option)
                        },
                        onDropdownSelected: {
                            eachCellStatus[index].isOpen.toggle()
                            if ( eachCellStatus[index].isOpen ){
                                let cellWithHighestZIndex = eachCellStatus.max(by: {$0.zIndex < $1.zIndex})
                                eachCellStatus[index].zIndex = (cellWithHighestZIndex?.zIndex ?? 0) + 1
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .zIndex(eachCellStatus[index].zIndex)
                }
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            
            Group {
                TextField("Full Address", text: $address)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 45)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct DropdownSelectorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DropdownSelectorView()
    }
}
```

Comment: drop down doesn't  show up when we have more than 1 elements in the list , Please have a look on the expected UI

Comment: Updated the code in the above answer, try now.

Comment: it works for first cell but not for other cell @khahttps://stackoverflow.com/users/5096960/khawar-ali

Comment: I got it its because  value was declared static , now it works perfect only problem when we try to open two cells simultaneously , first one goes below the ui,

Comment: Updated above code, try now. The only problem is, that we are setting the Z-Index for row (two cells) at the same time.

Comment: ok,  I ll try and update

Comment: Fixed all With `LazyVGrid`, Use the above code.

Comment: yeah , its perfect